XML tree structure, modify
I have an XML structure in SQL Server that represents hierarchical data, and I need to update each item's ItemNumber based on its position within the hierarchy. Here's what I have so far:
DECLARE @ItemsXml XML = 
    (
        SELECT  dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(ti.Title, @Language) AS 'EntityTitle',
                ti.[Order] AS 'ItemNumber',
                ti.ParentId as 'ParentId',
                ti.Id as 'Id',
                m.RegistrationNumber as 'RegistrationNumber',
                CONVERT(NVARCHAR, m.RegistrationDate, 4) AS 'RegistrationDate',
                dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(s.Title, @Language) AS 'EntityState',
                dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(mt.Title, @Language) AS 'MaterialTypeTitle',
                IIF(m.ProposerMPId is not null, 
                    dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(u.FirstName, @Language) + ' ' + dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(u.LastName, @Language), 
                    dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(m.ResponsibleProposer, @Language)) AS 'EntityProposer',
                dbo.AgendaSittingAtachments(ti.Id, @Language) AS 'AgendaSittingAttachment'
        FROM TreeItems AS ti
        INNER JOIN CategorizationLinks cl ON cl.CategorizationId = ti.CategorizationId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TreeItemValues tiv ON tiv.TreeItemId = ti.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Materials m ON m.Id = tiv.MaterialId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MaterialTypes mt on mt.Id = m.[Type]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Statuses s ON s.Id = m.[Status]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u ON u.Id = m.ProposerMPId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TreeItems tiParent ON tiParent.Id = ti.ParentId
        WHERE cl.SittingId = @ObjectId AND (m.[Type] IS NULL OR m.[Type] not in (24, 51, 57, 58))
        AND (ti.EmptyItemTypeId is null or tiParent.TreeItemTypeId <> 3) AND ti.ParentId is not null
        ORDER BY ti.[Order]
        FOR XML PATH ('Items')
    )

<Items>
  <EntityTitle>Receive and File a Report from Community Action of the County on the 2023-2024 Community Needs Assessment and Community Action Plan</EntityTitle>
  <ItemNumber>1</ItemNumber>
  <ParentId>E9BBEF90-0915-41F3-87D0-AAD943C0554F</ParentId>
  <Id>BC94E6D1-B8D8-44CE-A7CB-963A048FFCAF</Id>
  <EntityState>Business committee consideration</EntityState>
  <MaterialTypeTitle>Motion for adoption of the report</MaterialTypeTitle>
  <EntityProposer>Epar User1</EntityProposer>
</Items>
<Items>
  <EntityTitle>cat2</EntityTitle>
  <ItemNumber>1</ItemNumber>
  <ParentId>AD4F8BB1-0FE4-4078-BF34-9B509B20A723</ParentId>
  <Id>558CD287-BB26-4A76-9388-BC98CC486B30</Id>
</Items>
<Items>
  <EntityTitle>cat1</EntityTitle>
  <ItemNumber>2</ItemNumber>
  <ParentId>E9BBEF90-0915-41F3-87D0-AAD943C0554F</ParentId>
  <Id>B0B88E8A-CEAB-4023-9E1C-5F202131D146</Id>
</Items>
<Items>
  <EntityTitle>Annual appro #1</EntityTitle>
  <ItemNumber>2</ItemNumber>
  <ParentId>B0B88E8A-CEAB-4023-9E1C-5F202131D146</ParentId>
  <Id>E0B7B388-FB1B-4293-BA80-9FFD161732B2</Id>
  <EntityState>Committee consideration I reading</EntityState>
  <MaterialTypeTitle>Annual Appropriation Bill </MaterialTypeTitle>
  <EntityProposer>Epar User1</EntityProposer>
</Items>
<Items>
  <EntityTitle>Test Kiko Redirect</EntityTitle>
  <ItemNumber>2</ItemNumber>
  <ParentId>B0B88E8A-CEAB-4023-9E1C-5F202131D146</ParentId>
  <Id>AD4F8BB1-0FE4-4078-BF34-9B509B20A723</Id>
  <EntityState>Committee consideration I reading</EntityState>
  <MaterialTypeTitle>Annual Appropriation Bill </MaterialTypeTitle>
  <EntityProposer>epar_user15 test15</EntityProposer>
</Items>
<Items>
  <EntityTitle>Annual Appropriation Bill</EntityTitle>
  <ItemNumber>3</ItemNumber>
  <ParentId>B0B88E8A-CEAB-4023-9E1C-5F202131D146</ParentId>
  <Id>F551FB03-2794-4209-9C29-88C2862CCE57</Id>
  <EntityState>Committee consideration I reading</EntityState>
  <MaterialTypeTitle>Annual Appropriation Bill </MaterialTypeTitle>
  <EntityProposer>Simona Radinska Andovski</EntityProposer>
</Items>

The goal is to update the ItemNumber field so that items are numbered based on their hierarchical level. For example, if an item's parent is 1, its ItemNumber should be 1.1, 1.2, etc.
I tried using window functions directly in an UPDATE statement, but encountered limitations.
Could anyone suggest an alternative approach to efficiently update the ItemNumber field based on the hierarchical structure of the XML data?
Thanks!

Guess what? MySQL is a totally different product to SQL Server - do yourself a favour and correct your tags so the right experts look at your post.

And you need to show us before and after data... i.e. sample data before being updated, and again how it looks after being updated.

Generate the hierarchy string from TreeItems using recursive cte or whatever (of this there's a billion answers already), and then join the rest of the tables to generate the xml you want

Don't remove all your rdbms tags, but only tag onr

Based on the scalar function  dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue this suggests you are using SQL Server, however, it's you who needs to confirm which you are using, by [edit]ing your question and adding the appropriate tag.

Is XSLT an option? And if so which version? This transformation is easily implemented in a few lines of XSLT 3.0 code, but I don't know if that is an "efficient" solution in your database environment.

XSLT is never an option :D

Please edit your question, and add a desired XML output..

You can use a recursive CTE to build the item number up. Then join everything else to that.

You can't use WITH on a DECLARE or SET, you'll need a SELECT for that.
You need to cast the first row to nvarchar(4000) or nvarchar(max) otherwise you will get type binding errors.
Don't use n/varchar without a length.
Don't use '' to quote column names, only [] and only where necessary.
Use , TYPE on the FOR XML if you are going to keep it stored as the xml type.
The predicate tiParent.TreeItemTypeId <> 3 seems to only refer to the immediate parent, not the top of the tree. If the requirement is different then you need to change the CTE.
I don't know what dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue does, but it could probably be factored into an inline Table Valued Function, which is normally faster.

DECLARE @ItemsXml XML;

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT
        ti.[Order],
        ti.ParentId,
        ti.Id,
        ti.EmptyItemTypeId,
        ti.TreeItemTypeId,
        NULL AS ParentTreeItemTypeId,
        CAST(ti.[Order] AS nvarchar(4000)) AS ItemNumber
    FROM TreeItems ti
    WHERE ti.ParentId IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        ti.[Order],
        ti.ParentId,
        ti.Id,
        ti.EmptyItemTypeId,
        ti.TreeItemTypeId,
        cte.TreeItemTypeId,
        CONCAT(cte.ItemNumber, N'.', ti.[Order])
    FROM TreeItems ti
    JOIN cte tiParent ON tiParent.Id = ti.ParentId
)
SELECT @ItemsXml = 
    (
        SELECT
            dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(ti.Title, @Language) AS EntityTitle,
            ti.ItemNumber,
            ti.ParentId,
            ti.Id,
            m.RegistrationNumber,
            CONVERT(NVARCHAR(30), m.RegistrationDate, 4) AS RegistrationDate,
            dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(s.Title, @Language) AS EntityState,
            dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(mt.Title, @Language) AS MaterialTypeTitle,
            IIF(m.ProposerMPId is not null, 
                dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(u.FirstName, @Language) + ' ' + dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(u.LastName, @Language), 
                dbo.GetCurrentLanguageValue(m.ResponsibleProposer, @Language)) AS EntityProposer,
            dbo.AgendaSittingAtachments(ti.Id, @Language) AS AgendaSittingAttachment
        FROM cte AS ti
        INNER JOIN CategorizationLinks cl ON cl.CategorizationId = ti.CategorizationId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TreeItemValues tiv ON tiv.TreeItemId = ti.Id
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Materials m ON m.Id = tiv.MaterialId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN MaterialTypes mt on mt.Id = m.[Type]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Statuses s ON s.Id = m.Status
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Users u ON u.Id = m.ProposerMPId
        LEFT OUTER JOIN TreeItems tiParent ON tiParent.Id = ti.ParentId
        WHERE cl.SittingId = @ObjectId
          AND (m.[Type] IS NULL OR m.[Type] not in (24, 51, 57, 58))
          AND (ti.EmptyItemTypeId is null or ti.ParentTreeItemTypeId <> 3)
          AND ti.ParentId is not null
        ORDER BY ti.[Order]
        FOR XML PATH ('Items'), TYPE
    );

